# Any experience with cypress-social-login using Facebook provider?

Tags: facebook, authentication, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to make an automated test of the Facebook login feature in our web application in Cypress. I would like to skip the visual input of credentials and rather provide them programatically.
I came across the cypress-social-login plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-social-logins
Does anyone have the experience specifically with the implementation of this plugin for Facebook login? Or did anyone manage to automate Facebook login without any plugin?
Another question is: for the plugin to work, I have to provide a login url fom my application. But my application doesn´t have a specific login url. It uses a fullscreen modal that contains a Facebook login button. Is there a way to modify the plugin to deal with this?

Comment: smart users use 2FA, in that case it is luckily not possible to automate the login (i assume). either way, it is definitely not allowed and users should never enter their facebook password in any custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I accepted this fact. But I was successful by using another much simpler approach: First I go to facebook.com and log in there. Then I open my App and click the Facebook login button. In this way I can simulate the majority of users that are already signed in.
Unfortunately, when I run the tests on Lambdatest, Facebook won´t let me sign-in and tells me that I am misusing their services by going too fast :D
For now I am left by running tests locally.